# Custom segments / filters, which is the approach should I take for structuring google analytics in domain with many subfolders

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking for advice on how to best structure google analytics for best future use.  I have several sub directories under one domain which I would like to track separately.  Within these subdirectories there are also subdirectories for mobile or desktop visitors and I would like to collect usage information from there, so my folder structure goes.

```
www.mydomain.com/folder1/desktop
www.mydomain.com/folder1/mobile

www.mydomain.com/folder2/desktop
www.mydomain.com/folder2/mobile

www.mydomain.com/folder3/desktop
www.mydomain.com/folder3/mobile
```

I have read several articles on filtering and on custom segments, but I am still unclear as to which approach is best for my structure, and the more I read the more uncertain I become.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to track each of these locations separately, then you want to set up separate profiles for each case. You will need to configure it so that the tracking cookie is limited to just the path you are tracking.

If you are using the classic code you would call this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCookiePath', '/myBlogDirectory']);
```

If you are using the universal code you would do this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
   cookiePath: '/path/to/site'
});
```

Comment: I don't believe it's well known but setcookiepath is case sensitive so be careful. Wouldn't you say it's in favor of filter